# How can I improve the performance of this query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
DATE(DTM) AS 'Dia',
ROUND(AVG(TMP)-10) AS 'Graus Dia',
(SELECT 
ROUND(AVG(TMP),1) 
FROM dados_meteo 
WHERE HOUR(DTM)>=18 AND HOUR(DTM)<=22 AND DATE(DTM)=Dia/* AND POM = '[VARIABLE]'*/) AS 'Temp. Crepuscular'
FROM dados_meteo
/*WHERE POM = '[VARIABLE]'*/
GROUP BY DATE(DTM)
```

The structure of the table is:

```
POM Varchar 
DTM datetime 
RNF double 
WET double 
HMD double 
TMP double 
DEW double 
INF int
```

And the output of `explain select ...` is:

```
1 PRIMARY dados_meteo ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 18684 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 
2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY dados_meteo ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 18684 Using where
```

Comment: You can start by searching similar topics and finding out what data other people need in order to help when faced with questions like yours. Downvoted due to lack of bothering to accept answers and not providing sufficient info.

Comment: Give some more details: structure of the table `dados_meteo` + if possible please paste the output of `explain <query>` this query.

Comment: POM Varchar
DTM datetime
RNF double
WET double
HMD double
TMP double
DEW double
INF int

Comment: 1  PRIMARY  dados_meteo  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 18684  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  dados_meteo  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 18684  Using where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split `dtm` up in a date and time part.

```
datem date
timem time

SELECT
  datem AS 'Dia'
  ,ROUND(AVG(TMP)-10) AS 'Graus Dia'
  ,(SELECT ROUND(AVG(TMP),1) 
     FROM dados_meteo 
     WHERE timem BETWEEN maketime(18,0,0) AND maketime(22,0,0) 
     AND datem = Dia) AS 'Temp. Crepuscular'
FROM dados_meteo
GROUP BY datem
```

Make sure you use an index on `timem` and `datem`

Comment: Do I need to create new fields on the table?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use an index you have to replace dtm with a date-something and time-something field. Because you're splitting the field using functions now and that prevents any index you might have from working.

Answer (score -1):

At least create an index for `DTM`.

Comment: I don't really think the index on DTM would really be effective since he is wrapping the field in a function.

Comment: @Oliver M Grech I think you're right. Mysql apparently doesn't support indices based on functions.